# Error Messages not displaying in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to show error on my view but when i submit *register-designer* and after validation redirect to main view and there i want to display error this is not working how should i solve this.

My Controller:

```
public function designer_basic()
{
    if($this->form_validation->run('as_designer')==true){
        echo "good";
    }else{

        return redirect('Designers/as_designer');
    }
}
```

My View is:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-12">
<?php if(!empty(validation_errors())){?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
            <?php echo validation_errors();?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You should set rules to validate  post values in controller like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('as_designer', 'Designer', 'required');
```

[Check the documentation of Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#the-form)

Answer (score 0):

**You should set rules to the controller like this :**

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('as_designer', 'Designer', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
     ......
 } else {
     ......
 }
```

**I hope it's working fine for you.**